# Finding Image reference in MS Word using VBA

Tags: excel, ms-word, clipboard-pictures, vba

I am trying to copy an excel Table and image from MS EXCEL to MS WORD using VBA. I was struggling to find out how will I reference the tables and images into the Word once they are sent from excel.
After a long research I came across a very simple answer for table :

> ```
> Range("C1:D8").Copy
> Dim WDDoc As Word.Document
> Dim table1 As Word.Table
>
> Dim para As Paragraph
> Set para = WDDoc.Paragraphs.Add
>
> para.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteRTF,
> Placement:=wdInLine,
> DisplayAsIcon:=False
> ```
>
> set table1 = WDDoc.Tables(1) ' getting reference for the Pasted tables in word
>
> table1.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBlueGray

What I have done:
I am able to copy an image from excel and simply pasting it on to word doc. para.

What I need?
after copying n picture i am not able to refer to that picture in word and hence not able to edit or resize the image once it is pasted.

Comment: feel free to leave a comment or edit if you you think there is a better way to implemented the code that I have already written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
With ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count)
    .Height = 314.95 ' or whatever
End With
```

This assumes that the picture is pasted "in line with text" (as you do) and is the last (furthest down) in-line picture in the document.

Comment: **para.range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteShape, Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False ... but is giving error

Comment: What error? Why are you copying a range of cells `Range("C1:D8")` instead of just the image? e.g. using `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 2").Copy` or similar. I can see Word not wanting to paste a range of cells as a `wdPasteShape`.